# CSS-styles do not load when using Vuetify Automatic a la Carte

Tags: css, vue.js, vuetify.js

I've been working on a project for quite some time now and everything was working fine. Recently I had some issues with starting up my project, so I decided to reinstall vue-cli and vuetify to the latest version. Now I have the problem that the css code of my components doesn't seem to load. All the margins, colors, etc. are wrong.

I have been searching around, but I cannot find the potential cause of the issue.

My current code set-up:

`main.js`:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'
import store from './store'

import './plugins/vuetify'
import vuetify from './plugins/vuetify';

Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  vuetify,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

`/plugins/vuetify.js`:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuetify from 'vuetify/lib';

Vue.use(Vuetify);

export default new Vuetify({
  icons: {
    iconfont: 'mdi',
  },
  theme: {
    primary: '#FFCA28',
    secondary: '#1976D2',
    accent: '#82B1FF',
    error: '#FF5252',
    info: '#2196F3',
    success: '#4CAF50',
    warning: '#FB8C00'
  }
});
```

(Also tried:)

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuetify from 'vuetify/lib';
import 'vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css'

Vue.use(Vuetify);

export default new Vuetify({
  icons: {
    iconfont: 'mdi',
  },
  theme: {
    primary: '#FFCA28',
    secondary: '#1976D2',
    accent: '#82B1FF',
    error: '#FF5252',
    info: '#2196F3',
    success: '#4CAF50',
    warning: '#FB8C00'
  }
});
```

In `App.vue` I have:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <v-app id="inspire">
      <v-content>
        <Header></Header>
        <router-view></router-view>
      </v-content>
    </v-app>
  </div>
</template>
```

I tried using both the quick-start and the a-la-carte (treeshaking) documentation on the vuetify website, but no luck.

Any thoughts, ideas?

Thank you in advance!

Jeroen

Comment: any solution for this?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. There was a mismatch with the vuetify version and some of my dependencies in my package.json. Re-installing vuetify and the dependencies did the trick